# Cannot start listening to ManagementEventWatcher

Tags: c#, wmi

I have implemented a solution as per [this here example](https://gist.github.com/M0n7y5/b45669c238ff3f2602c1859b3829137c) where I listen to serial port changes. Normally this worked good but recently I have started stress testing the application and noticed that in certain situations this does not work.

**Situation 1:**

I have no serial ports. Nothing is connected. The code fails at the `deviceAttachWatcher.Start();`. So this is the first point where the code should start listening for changes. The error message is *NotSupported*. If I look in EventViewer under Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/WMI-Activity/Operation I can find an entry with following message:

> Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; ClientMachine = xyz; User
> = DOMAIN\user.name; ClientProcessId = 16548; Component = Unknown; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecNotificationQuery - root\WMI :
> select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance
> ISA 'MSSerial_PortName'; ResultCode = 0x80041032; PossibleCause =
> Unknown

**Situation 2:**

I have one serial port. The code does not fail at `deviceAttachWatcher.Start();`. It even goes through the second call `deviceDetachWatcher.Start();`. The application is not listening to changes on serial ports but if I connect or disconnect this device nothing happens. I get two entries in the Event Viewer.

- Entry 1

> Namespace = root\WMI; NotificationQuery = select * from
> __InstanceCreationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance ISA 'MSSerial_PortName'; UserName = DOMAIN\user.name;
> ClientProcessID = 20260, ClientMachine = xyz; PossibleCause =
> Temporary

- Entry 2

> Namespace = root\WMI; NotificationQuery = select * from
> __InstanceDeletionEvent within 1 where TargetInstance ISA 'MSSerial_PortName'; UserName = DOMAIN\user.name;
> ClientProcessID = 20260, ClientMachine = xyz; PossibleCause =
> Temporary

These two event entries correspond to my two queries.

**Situation 3:**

I have 2 serial ports connected. Code works as expected.

**QUESTION**

Obviously, I would like the situation 3 to be the constant. What is happening in situations 1 and 2? Why am I getting "NotSupported" error?

Initially I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669672/the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permi) problem as well but I fixed it as per answer so now I do not get this log entry in the Event Viewer anymore(this one was under Windows Logs/System).

**UPDATE**

I just tested this on my colleagues machine and he has the same issue so environment as a problem is out.

Comment: There is a [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/system-management-components/wmi-activity-event-5858-logged-with-resultcode-0x80041032) for this mishap.  Plug&play is never not a problem with serial ports, be sure that a program that uses the ports has closed them and use the "Safely remove hardware" tray icon before removing a device.

Comment: I came across this page already and it doesn't help me. I have restarted the PC without any hardware connected so I expect that no other program was using the port once I started my application.