# MSAL.NET (permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID)

Tags: .net, azure-virtual-machine, azure-ad-msal, azure-virtual-network, msal.js

I am implementing MSAL.NET on my asp.net core api.

Below is my example code. It works perfectly fine when I run it on my local machine. The login from MSAL popups.

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
  .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
  .WithTenantId(tenantId)
  .Build();

var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

When I deploy it on Azure Virtual Machine. The Login from MSAL doesn't popup and it will always in pending state. I check the event logs and it gives me this error logs below:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
{3480A401-BDE9-4407-BC02-798A866A****}
 and APPID
{30AD8C8E-AE85-42FA-B9E8-7E99E3DF****}
 to the user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool SID (S-1-5-82-3713467212-4047885013-3661040889-683609825-2140) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

[image]

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try with this solution

**1)**  Open the registry editor as an administrator and navigate to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID Or APP ID**. There is  the APPID as a value. Remember the application name, you can see in the Data column, the corresponding Name column shows (Default).

**2)**  On the left pane: **Right-click on the APPID ke**y and  select **Permissions**:

[image]

**3)**  on **Permissions** window, click **Advanced**.  click **Change and type your administrator account**. Then click **OK**.

[image]

**4)**  double-click to **open Administrators entry**. Select the **Full Control** checkbox in order to give full permissions to Administrators and press OK .

[image]

**5)** Then Modify the permission on the **COM Server application** .Open the **component service** and Simultaneously open the **dcomcnfg**

**6)** Expand **Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config**.From **View** menu choose **Detail**.

**7)**  **Right-click** on the **APPID** name (e.g. in "PerAppRuntimeBroker" in this example) and select **Properties**.

[image]

**8)** select the  **Security** tab, click **Edit on Launch & Activation Permissions**

[image]

**9)** Click the name that applies to you and click the appropriate permission.

For more details refer this documents:

1. https://www.wintips.org/fix-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-com-server-application/#image
2. [The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669672/the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permi)

Comment: Hi @ShruitiJoshi-MT it doesn't work. Still the issue occurs. And the MSAL Popup Login still doesn't popup.

Comment: getting same error or different one?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried with restart or re connect to the  VM after doing above steps?